# Shaping json object

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

```
rows[
  {0: c:[{0: {v:'2013'}, 1: {v: 'apple'},2: {v: '200'}}]},
  {1: c:[{0: {v:'2014'}, 1: {v: 'apple'},2: {v: '1000'}}]},
  {2: c:[{0: {v:'2013'}, 1: {v: 'orange'},2: {v: '200'}}]},
  {3: c:[{0: {v:'2014'}, 1: {v: 'orange'},2: {v: '1000'}}]}
]
```

I am trying to reshape it into something like this:

```
[apple: {2013: '200', 2014: '1000'}, orange: {2013: '200', 2014: '1000'}]
```

OR

```
[
  apple: {
    2013: {year: '2013', amount: '200'},
    2014: {year: '2014', amount: '1000'}
  },
  orange: {
    2013: {year: '2013', amount: '200'},
    2014: {year: '2014', amount: '1000'}
}]
```

OR
apple: [{year:2013, amount:200},{year:2014,amount:1000}]

I have tried playing with lodash's *.map,*.uniq,*.reduce,*.zipObject but I am still unable to figure it out.

Comment: Object of `2013` storing `2013` seems like bad data integrity to me. Why not just an array? `apple: [{year:2013, amount:200},{year:2014,amount:1000}]`

Comment: Okay how do I achieve that? I am still trying, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Maddy, basically just loop through your rows and build the new object that you want. What is the part you are getting stuck on?

Comment: I have separated out unique apple and orange, now I want to merge it with two years with different amounts. Believe me I have tried almost 3-4 days playing with lodash's function. I am kind of new to javascript. Please try it and let me know if its really that easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the following lodash functions:
Get the name of fruits using _.map.
uniqueFruitNames = Get the unique names by _.uniq and then sort them.
data2013 and data2014 = Use _.remove to get fruits of particular year and sort them respectively.
Use _.zipObject to zip uniqueFruitsName and data2013
uniqueFruitsName and data2014
Then _.merge the two zipped Objects.

```
var dataSeries = _.map(mergedData, function(asset,key) { 
                return { 
                    name: key, 
                    data: [fruit[0].amount, fruit[1].amount]
                }
        });
```